# downloading a pdf file, audio and video files from webserver through android

Tags: android

I have created an android app. That needs to download pdf, audio and video files from my asp.net web api to my android application. But I dont have an idea of how my web api code would be like and my android download code for pdf, audio files and video files would look like.
Thanks for your perusal.

Comment: Please google/research more before ask question. Your question is like "Hey I need an Android app and server, can You write it for me?"

Comment: Thanks alot @Sebastian.  Comments noted. I am currently doing research on the said subject. I just pasted this cos I behind  on time lines in my project. I really apologize if I have broken the rules of posting  in anyway. I appreciate that every developer must be willing to do research to excel in the profession. Thanks alot. fully noted in case of next post

Comment: I've posted http download code, but as @Sebastian said you must search more

Comment: you may accept and vote if you find it helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize and use this, you will need the wakelock permission to prevent interruption

```
@SuppressLint("Wakelock")
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{

    private Context context;

    public DownloadTask(Context context ,Dialog dialog, ProgressBar progressBar ,TextView progressTextView , String destinationPath ,String fileName , JSONObject jObject )
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl)
    {
        String directory = sUrl[0];
        String fileName = sUrl[1];


        //prevent CPU from going off if the user presses the power button during download
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());
        wl.acquire();

        //download
        try
        {
            new File(directory).mkdirs();
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                //connect to url
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[2]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();


                // check for http_ok (200)
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                    return "Server returned HTTP "
                            + connection.getResponseCode() + " "
                            + connection.getResponseMessage();


                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                // download the file
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                output = new FileOutputStream(directory+"/"+fileName+".mp3");//change extension

                //copying
                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
                {
                    // allow canceling
                    if (isCancelled())
                    {
                        new File(directory+"/"+fileName+".mp3").delete();//delete partially downloaded file
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    if (fileLength > 0 ) //publish progress only if total length is known
                        publishProgress( (int)(total/1024) , fileLength/1024 );//(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.toString();
            }
            finally //closing streams and connection
            {
                try
                {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ignored)
                {
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            wl.release(); // release the lock screen
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override // onPreExecute and onProgressUpdate run on ui thread so you can update ui from here
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if (result != null)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Download error: " + result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
        {
                Toast.makeText(context, " download complete ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

and then call it from main

```
new DownloadTask(this).execute( dirPath , fileName , urlToDownload );
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I would try your suggestion and what I have in my research and possibly edit the question. If I encounter any problem. Thanks alot.